# how get first row from duplicata values Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Below you can find my table with values (there are no constraints on my table):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM khalil;
```

outputs:

> ```
> ID VALUE
> -- -------
>  1 yassine
>  1 khalil
>  2 amine
> ```

I need to get the first row when I have duplicate values.

I have two rows with **`id = 1`** so, in this case, I need that the first one,
which is **`id = 1`** and **`value = 'yassine'`**

Comment: There is no *first* record unless you have a column to order the results...

Comment: there is a solution using oracle to create temporary column to order the results?

Comment: Oracle can only use existing columns to predictably order results. Otherwise the order in which rows are returned are not guaranteed. If you want to guarantee that yassine is the row returned with id = 1, then you need to add another sequence column that gives a distinct value for each id and order by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM khalil
WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM khalil GROUP BY id)
ORDER BY id
```

This will return the first row for each id.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really care which `value` you'll get (unless there's something you can use to distinguish values), aggregates - such as `min` or `max` - can help:

```
SQL> select id,
  2         max(value) value
  3  from khalil
  4  group by id
  5  order by id;

        ID VALUE
---------- --------------------
         1 yassine
         2 amine

SQL>
```

Alternatively, using analytic functions (such as `row_number`, which lets you *sort* values), you'd do it as follows:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id,
  3            value,
  4            row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) rn
  5     from khalil
  6    )
  7  select id,
  8         value
  9  from temp
 10  where rn = 1
 11  order by id;

        ID VALUE
---------- --------------------
         1 yassine
         2 amine

SQL>
```